# MVC 5 windows authentication for web site on different domain without login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an MVC 5, C# (.NET 4.5) web site deployed on a test server. The domain for this server is DEV.local and I am using IIS 7.5.

I need for the site to allow for users to connect from a different domain, PROD.com. I am also on this account from my current computer.

I need for the users to be able to connect using their current Windows account without having to use a login page.

I have tried numerous solutions using Windows authentication along with various combinations of web.config settings in the authorization section, and I am unable to connect from the PROD.com domain without getting a login page.

Please show me how to connect to this web site from a different domain without a login page.

App Pool
Managed pipeline mode: Integrated
Identity: Network service

Web Site
Authentication
Only Windows Authentication is enabled. The rest are disabled. 
Providers are Negotiate then NTLM
Enabled Kernel Mode-authentication is enabled.

The windows web folder has permissions set to allow Authenticated Users.

EDIT - I installed IIS 7 on my local box to remove the domain trust possibility that someone described in the comments section. I have the same configuration on my local box using IIS 7 and I am still challenged with a login screen.

Web.config – relevant section

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpModules>
<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
```

Controller code

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
            return View();
        }
```

Layout page – relevant section

```
<div class="pull-right"><h3 style="color: #8b8073;">@ViewBag.UserName</h3></div>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to set up a trust between those domains or use domain federation?  (via domain and authentication, domain admin)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean as i am new to this. How do I check?

Comment: Talk with your domain admin. Ask if he/she would be willing to set up a trust or federation between the two domains.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I have this done, will i need to do anything else to get this working?

Comment: Your domain admin might not want to allow all users (from the other domain) full permissions, so bring a list of users (from the other domain) who need access and some description of what they need (servers, services, stuff like that).